# Replace existing values in a table with new values from a list Randomly.

Tags: sql, sql-server, random

Simple table

```
    Date       |ChannelID 

    01/01/2001 | 1001
    02/01/2001 | 1001
    03/01/2001 | 1001
    04/01/2001 | 1001
    05/01/2001 | 1001
    06/01/2001 | 1001
```

I need to replace the ChannelID values with either 1001, 2001, or 2002, randomly on each row.

Ive tried doing the following but didnt seem to give me random entries, and missed off the last value for some reason.

```
    update A

set ChannelID = (
    SELECT TOP 1 b.q
    FROM (
        SELECT 1001 AS q

        UNION ALL

        SELECT 2001

        UNION ALL

        SELECT 2002
        ) b
        CROSS APPLY (
  SELECT TOP 1 b2.q2
    FROM (
        SELECT 1001 AS q2

        UNION ALL

        SELECT 2001

        UNION ALL

        SELECT 2002
        ) b2
WHERE b.q <> b2.q2
ORDER BY newid()
) b2    
    ORDER BY NEWID()
)
From A
```

Is there an elegant way of achieving this without using temp/variable tables?

Apologies if this is a similar post, but could not find anything without the use of temp tables etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try the following:

```
declare @tab table ([Date] date, ChannelID int)

insert into @tab
select '01/01/2001', 1001 union
select '02/01/2001', 1001 union
select '03/01/2001', 1001 union
select '04/01/2001', 1001 union
select '05/01/2001', 1001 union
select '06/01/2001', 1001 

select [Date], CASE ascii(newid()) % 3 WHEN 0 THEN '1001' WHEN 1 THEN '2001' ELSE '2002' END AS ChannelID
FROM @tab
```

**Weighted Randomness**

```
drop table if exists #tmp
CREATE TABLE #tmp (rnd_val int, weights int)
INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES (1001, 54);
INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES (2001, 27);
INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES (2002, 21);

update @tab set ChannelID = null

while ((select count(1) from @tab where ChannelID is null) > 0)
begin
    ;with cte as
    (select top 1 [Date], ChannelID from @tab where ChannelID is null)
    update cte set ChannelID = (select top 1 rnd_val from #tmp order by RAND(CAST(NEWID() AS VARBINARY)) * weights desc)
end
select * from @tab
```

Comment: This appears to be ok, however I'm trying to achieve the same goal without temp/variable tables. :)

Comment: temp table is just for the test run purposes; you can directly apply it as update statement.

Comment: Brilliant, yes of course. Thank you. As an additional challenge, any idea on how to 'weight' the randomness? Eg 70% 1001, 20% 2001, and 10% 2002?

Comment: For weighted randomness, we need to provide the weights for each random value and assign each row a channelID based on random value picked after applying the weights in the calculation. Please see the added section in my answer. The weights which I chose gives the following distribution 
of randomly picked value when executed 1 million times (70% 1001, 20% 2001, 10% 2002)

Comment: 1001 (699487 - 69.95%), 
2001 (199728 - 19.97%),
2002 (100785 - 10.08%)

Answer (score 2):

You can do :

```
update t 
     set t.ChannelID  = tt.q
from table t cross apply
     ( select top (1) tt.q
       from ( values (1001), (2001), (2002) 
            ) tt (q)
       where cast(tt.q as varchar(255)) <> t.date
       order by newid()
     ) tt;
```

Comment: Is there `tt.id` column available?

Comment: The date is causing issues in randomly distributing the new values. Suppose the table did not contain any dates, just **ChannelID**. How do I iterate through each row and randomly assign a replacement value of either 1001, 2001, or 2002? Using your example above and removing the where clause stops generating new values for each row (all values end up being assigned either 1001, 2001, or 2002.)